# Bootstrap 3 tooltip removes linebreaks \n of content in title

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

**SOLVED**

I try to display a php variable that has linebreaks set to this format "\n" in it and appears as this in the title without tooltip

```
Test1

Test2

Test3
```

But the tooltip make them appear as this :
**Test1
Test2
Test3**

I have set **data-html="true"** in the tag, but I still have this issue.

Is there a way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: Line breaks in HTML are ignored when it is rendered. You'll need to replace them with `<br />` tags. How you do that depends on the exact format of your string, and whether you're looking to make the change on the server or client side. Please amend the question to include more of that detail

Comment: You are right, It just worked with <br> instead